# Rails Searchkick not returning results when I use a where statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I run

```
Post.search("daniel")
```

I get 60+ results

```
Post.where(archive: true)
```

I get 60+ results

```
Post.search("daniel", where: { archive: true } 

Here is the full searchkick query.
```

I get 0 results

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "dis_max": {
                "queries": [
                  {
                    "multi_match": {
                      "query": "daniel",
                      "boost": 10,
                      "operator": "and",
                      "analyzer": "searchkick_search",
                      "fields": [
                        "*.analyzed"
                      ],
                      "type": "best_fields"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "multi_match": {
                      "query": "daniel",
                      "boost": 10,
                      "operator": "and",
                      "analyzer": "searchkick_search2",
                      "fields": [
                        "*.analyzed"
                      ],
                      "type": "best_fields"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "multi_match": {
                      "query": "daniel",
                      "boost": 1,
                      "operator": "and",
                      "analyzer": "searchkick_search",
                      "fuzziness": 1,
                      "prefix_length": 0,
                      "max_expansions": 3,
                      "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                      "fields": [
                        "*.analyzed"
                      ],
                      "type": "best_fields"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "multi_match": {
                      "query": "daniel",
                      "boost": 1,
                      "operator": "and",
                      "analyzer": "searchkick_search2",
                      "fuzziness": 1,
                      "prefix_length": 0,
                      "max_expansions": 3,
                      "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
                      "fields": [
                        "*.analyzed"
                      ],
                      "type": "best_fields"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "archive": {
              "value": true
            }
...
```

I looked at the searchkick gem doc and I am following exactly what they have listed to do. The normal search works fine and it only returns 0 posts when I add the where clause.

Without the where clause it shows all the posts which have "daniel" in the and it breaks when the where clause is added.

What am I doing wrong here? Is more information needed?

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick text_start: [:title]
```

Comment: The bottom of the results shows `"filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "archive": {
              "value": false
            }`, implying that the search was for `archive: false` not true. Is this the wrong log or is that a clue.

Comment: And this may be a stupid question but how are you certain that there should be results for `Daniel` AND archive: true. Just because they each return results separately doesn't necessarily mean we'd expect results when both are used.

Comment: Post.where("title ILIKE ? and archive = false", "%#{paras[:terms]}%") works fine but the search still doesnt work.

Comment: Can you add your searchkick settings in the `Post` model

Comment: added on the bottom.